# Quero reutilizar um componente Input no Vue 3, mas não consigo passar função por Props

Tags: vue.js, componentes, vue-router

Eu tenho um arquivo que contém um componente input(Estilizei com Bootstrap).
Eu chamo esse input em 2 arquivos diferentes. Consegui passar o placeholder por meio de Props.
Porém, não consegui passar função por meio de Props.
Nesse meu projeto, eu tenho duas telas Pai: PrimeiraTela.vue e a SegundaTela.vue
Nesses dois arquivos eu importo esse Input, eu gostaria de saber como posso chamar uma função diferente nesses dois arquivos no momento que eu importo o input ???

Por exemplo, quando importo o input na PrimeiraTela.vue, eu gostaria de passar por props uma função chamada de "funcRedirectOne", aí o arquivo do input vai ter um @click dentro desse input que vai chamar essa "funcRedirectOne", e aí eu desenvolvo a lógica dessa "funcRedirectOne", pode ser algo super simples como somente redirecionar para uma nova tela chamada "RedirecionamentoUm.vue".

A mesma ideia pra SegundaTela.vue:  eu passaria uma props com uma função chamada "funcRedirectTwo", ai dentro do arquivo do componente input eu desenvolvo a lógica dessa "funcRedirectTwo" e posso redirecionar pra uma nova tela chamada "RedirecionamentoDois.vue".
Desse jeito eu conseguiria reutilizar o input pra quantas telas e funções diferentes fosse necessário.
ABAIXO VOU COLOCAR COMO ESTÁ MINHA LINHA DE CÓDIGO NO ARQUIVO DO INPUT

```
//Este é o meu arquivo do inputReutilizavel. Deixei comentado as duas funções de redirecionamento. Minha ideia inicial era receber por props alguma dessas duas funções que foram passadas pelo componente pai, e aí ter uma propriedade @click dentro dessa tag <img />, pra que eu chame a função passada por props após clicar nessa imagem. 

    <template>
      <div class="input-group flex-nowrap ms-4">
        <span class="input-group-text border border-dark" id="addon-wrapping">
          <img src="../../components/Icons/IconSearch.png" style="width: 30px"
    // ***EU GOSTARIA DE INSERIR AQUI uma props com o @click pra receber as funções dos componentes pai
           />
        </span>
        <input
          type="text"
          :placeholder="textPlaceholder"
          class="form-control border border-dark rounded-right"
          aria-label="Username"
          aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
        />
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    // import router from "../router/index";
    
    export default {
      props: {
        textPlaceholder: String,
      },
      setup(props) {
        // const funcRedirectOne = (): any => {
        //   return router.push("/redirecionamentoum");
        // };
        // const funcRedirectTwo = (): any => {
        //   return router.push("/redirecionamentodois");
        // };
        // return {
        //   funcRedirectOne,
        //   funcRedirectTwo,
        // };
      },
    };
    </script>


//OBSERVAÇÃO FINAL: o código importante a se  mostrar foi esse do input.  Todos outros arquivos são muito curtos.
Nos arquivos  PrimeiraTela.vue e SegundaTela.vue  eu apenas coloco uma mensagem de sucesso com tag H1 e também importo o compomente do input, passando(por enquanto) uma props textPlaceholder com algum texto.

Nos arquivos RedirecionamentoUm.vue e RedirecionamentoDois.vue eu somente coloco outro mensagem de sucesso com a tag H1. O código principal está nesse do input mesmo.
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

Essa não é a melhor forma de fazer redirecionamento de pagina mas ai está o código que pode te ajudar. `This.CaminhoDaPagina` é a prop nela vai o numero da pagina que você quer dependendo do numero vai para pagina diferente, mas isso não é escalável. Na documentação do vue tem o que ele aceita passar como prop, uma dessas coisas é o retorno de uma função, não achei se é possível passar uma função.[Doc Vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-passing-details)

```js
<script>
export default {
    name:  "Teste",
    props: {
        textPlaceholder: {
            type:    String,
            default: ()=>""
        },
        caminhoPaginaSeguinte: {
            type:    Number,
            default: ()=>0
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setup()
        {
            let pagina = this.caminhoPaginaSeguinte;
            switch (true)
            {
            case (pagina === 1):
                console.log("foi para pagina 1");
                // Router.push("/redirecionamentoum");
                break;

            case (pagina === 2):
                console.log("foi para pagina 2");
                // Router.push("/redirecionamentodois");
                break;
        
            default:
                console.log("Fui para home");
                // Router.push("/redirecionamentoHome");
                break;
            }
        },
    }
};
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap ms-4">
        <span id="addon-wrapping" class="input-group-text border border-dark">
            <img
                src="@/assets/img/cartao-de-visita.jpg"
                style="width: 30px"
                @click="setup"
            >
        </span>
        <input
            type="text"
            :placeholder="textPlaceholder"
            class="form-control border border-dark rounded-right"
            aria-label="Username"
            aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
        >
    </div>
</template>

 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true console: true babel: true -->
```